# Android SOAP wsdl

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to connect to a Webservice from SOAP. I developed the SOAP Webservice in PHP and it's working fine (tried in Visual Studio).

First of all, this is the error:

```
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:144)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:126)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:179)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:116)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:111)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at com.example.FirstExample.CategoriesActivity.onCreate(CategoriesActivity.java:49)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-27 06:28:07.724: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     ... 11 more
```

The full error you can view here: http://pastebin.com/cRQ66vrj

And this is my code in Java:

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://10.0.0.20/soap/test_wsdl";
private final String URL = "http://10.0.0.20/info_send/encode.php?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://10.0.0.20/info_send/encode.php/select_data";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "select_data";
private String Webresponse = "";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response;
            response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            Webresponse = response.toString();
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.e("VALUE: ", Webresponse);
```

I've been following several tutorials, but none of them adapt to my needs. So I'm trying to create a method which does what I want. 
Also, I added to Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

What Am I doing wrong? 
Also, if you could point me a direction so I could get item by item the values retrieved with the code above, I would thank you. Something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= variable.size; i++){
   Log.e("Value: ", variable[i].ToString())
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I edit my answer, see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your logs

```
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
```

Be sure that your SOAP request runs in  `AsyncTask` (or in Service).

If you run it in main Thread (aka in Activity) it can lead to above mentioned error.

Information about AsyncTask you can found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) some example

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the exception clearly tells what's wrong with your code

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You cannot perform long running network operations on the main thread.
Move at least the last method call to an asynchronous method, you can do it like this,

```
ExecutorService mExec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    mExec.execute(new Runnable() {          
                @Override
                public void run() {             
                    try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    }catch(Exception exc){
                        exc.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

I had to add this line to make ksoap2 work with my web-services
            androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag(K.STR_XML_VERSION);

I also set following SOAP envelope properties

```
        envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENV;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.implicitTypes = false;
```

Comment: `final Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();        String `strRet = result.toString(); // to get return value

Comment: `final Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();  
String strRet = result.toString();
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txt.setText(strRet);`
But it's not giving any value. It's giving an Orange message: `09-27 07:30:40.094: W/System.err(3171): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive`

Comment: sorry, I don't know what's the problem this time round. I've checked and double checked, same code is working for me. Besides, the error sounds like you're trying to make a SoapPrimitive out of a String somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask to do network related operations...

Below is another solution:
Just add below lines in your code.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: Hm, I don't know the code, but isn't that trying to force something?

Comment: Where did you added these 2 lines? you need to add them above your request object..

Comment: OK, but this is not advisable code, always use AsyncTask for network operations...