# How to best use PHP Soap with Android?

Tags: java, php, android, web-services, soap

I'm trying to get the info from a SOAP in PHP and I achieve that task with the help in this post [Android SOAP wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048776/android-soap-wsdl). Although, there are a few things missing that I would like you to explain to me and give me a better option.

Currently, my PHP code is:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM `oc_category_description`");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
$all = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){
       $all[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
}
return json_encode($all);
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
exit();
```

And in Java Android I read it this way:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
Object response = (Object) envelope.getResponse();        

String strRet = response.ToString();

TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txt.setText(strRet);
```

With this code I can retrieve the info, but it's not the best way, the info comes like this example:

```
[{'name':'Google'},{'name':'ol\u00f3'},{'name':'yahoo'}]
```

Further than being shown this way, it comes with special characters. And I want to avoid them.

For me the best way would be something like the code below (I'm seeing this examples all over Google):

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getProperty(0);
```

And therefore I would get an array list (length, etc), and I could manage the items better.

Although, I've tried that solution and gives me the error:

> 9-27 07:30:40.094: W/System.err(3171): java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject

I do believe that the problem could be on my PHP, so I'm currently trying **without success**:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM `oc_category_description`");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($name);
$query->store_result();
$all = array();
while($query->fetch()){
     $all[] = array('nome' => $row);
}
$query->close();
$db->close();
return json_encode($all);
```

What do you recommend? Parse the current values I can get? If so, how? And if I have more than 1 column, and what's the best approach for special characters?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working this way:

```
String strRet = response.toString();
String[] lines = strRet.split(",");
List<String> array_cat = new ArrayList<String>()

 for(int i = 0; i <= lines.length - 1; i++){
    String cat = lines[i].substring(10, lines[i].length() - 2);
    array_cat.add(cat);
}
```

But I'm still with the problem of encoding. I know that the problem comes from PHP, if anyone have any solution, I appreciate.